# how to render my contact form within a index/home page

Tags: django, templates, view

I have a contact page attached within a index/home page. It does not have any contact.html page. How can i give url to the contact in my navigation bar so that it slides down to the contact page in the same home page.

> index.html

```
    <div class="nav-container">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'company:home' %}">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'company:about' %}">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'company:services' %}">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'company:blog' %}">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li> # what url should i have to give here so that it gives the contact page within this index page
                        </ul>
                    </div>

 <!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">Contact Us
            <p>HOW TO CONNECT WITH US ?</p>
            <span class="underline"></span>
        </h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="map">
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d7066.152739935275!2d85.3461636!3d27.6840344!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x39eb19a18187378f%3A0x8ba2460dd7896e64!2sOnline+Zeal!5e0!3m2!1sen!2snp!4v1553841516009!5m2!1sen!2snp" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form action="{% url 'company:contact' %}" method="post">
                     {% csrf_token %}
                    <label for="full-name">Full Name *</label>
                    <input id="name" type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control">
                    <label for="full-name">Email Address *</label>
                    <input id="full-name" type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                    <label for="full-name">Comment (if any)</label>
                    <textarea name="comment" rows="3" class="form-control" ></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-alternate">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

> views.py

```
def homepage(request):
services = Service.objects.filter(active=True)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        contact = form.save(commit=False)
        contact.save()
    else:
        messages.error(request,'Error in Form.')
else:
    form = ContactForm()
return render(request,'company/index.html',{'services':services,'form':form})
```

> forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Contact
    fields = ['full_name','email','comment']
```

> urls.py

```
path('',views.homepage,name='home'),
path('contact/',views.contact,name='contact'),
```

Comment: try giving `<a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>`

Answer (score 2):

In nav bar use href and hash #:

```
 <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">contact</a>
        </li>
```

then in contact itself you will give it id:

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="contact">
```

Of course you may use `<div>`  tag or any tag you prefer,